# Are cubes not a good geometry for environmental mapping?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I've been building out a scene with many cubes using this example from Three.js for reference: [THREE.js Environmental Mapping](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2)

I've noticed that spheres, torus', etc. look great with this sort of mapping, however, flat surfaces like the ones on a cube look terrible. Is there a better way of doing environmental mapping for a scene with many cubes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are seeing is that a flat surface has sharp edges, and so the environment map comes suddenly into view and passes suddenly out of view, and the result is jarring because there is no sense of what will come next over the course of a rotation.

With a taurus/sphere/anything with rounded edges, we get a distorted preview of whatever will rotate into view, and so the experience is less jarring. At leas that's my take on it.

Also the square will give a more 1:1 reflection of the resolution of the map, whereas a sphere will compress more like PI/2 : 1 pixel data into the same cross section, so it makes your reflections look higher quality than they are, because it shrinks them.

I'd say that those two factors are probably what you are seeing. Try doubling the resolution of your map when using cubes as any pixelation will be more obvious.

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense... The cube reflects perfectly, but in this instance a perfect reflection of a fake environment is not optimal.